# Is there a good Socket framework for C#?

Tags: c#, sockets, frameworks

after many days of search, I'm here to ask you this simple question : Is there a good Socket (TCP/IP) framework for C# ?

I'm quite new to C#, i came from java where I used to use Apache MINA.
In my search i found "SuperSocket", but it's not commented at all and the online documentation is not the most accurate. So it's not a charm to use it...

Thank you.

Comment: [System.Net.Sockets](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.aspx)?

Comment: I already look at System.Net.Sockets, but it's still to raw. I'm kinda looking for a MINA C# equivalent. SuperSocket would be exactly what i'm looking for, but as i said, it's not commented.

Comment: Matgieu, have a look here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209372/wcf-vs-sockets

Comment: I've started to write one which is inspired by Netty. I haven't had time to complete it yet though: https://github.com/jgauffin/griffin/tree/master/Source/Griffin.Networking