# C# socket client-server libraries (Nuget/other?)

Tags: c#, sockets, nuget, client-server

I want to start writing games/applications with client-server architecture. I explored the internet and everyone tells that the best way is to use c# built-in socket libs. But If I am forced to write everything on my own (singletons, threads, keeping connection alive, parsing in-out messages etc.) I bet I will do it for months. Do you know any library supporting client-server based connections for C# (Forms/WPF/maybe Mono)? I can not find any "quite new" threads/information about this.

Comment: This is too broad, but https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/whats-wcf might be a good place to start.

Comment: @PoweredByOrange I've written about WCF, and people tell that performance is quite low and maybe it will be good for applications, but it won't be fast enough for games (people write about 3-4 requests per second). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5209372/wcf-vs-sockets

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem will be, that you will not find an predefined lib which fits your requirements. 
But if you write it with Visual Studio autocomplete will help you a lot.

However there are lots of question for me. What exactly is your target? What kind of game do you thinking of?

These factors affect your complexity of your "socket" enormous.
I think for a small "Ping Pong"-Multiplayer-Game your Socket is quite easy to do.